# Display sub categories and their data of a taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, advanced-taxonomy-queries

I want to output the sub category details of a taxonomy

```
$getTerms = get_terms($taxonomy, $args);
print_r($getTerms);
```

When i print the above out it returns the object. But theres no value difference between parent and sub categories. The first is a parent taxonomy and the second is a sub-category.

```
[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [term_id] => 23
        [name] => Corporate teams
        [slug] => corporate-teams
        [term_group] => 0
        [term_taxonomy_id] => 23
        [taxonomy] => team_names
        [description] => Description of corporate team
        [parent] => 0
        [count] => 0
        [image_id] => 0
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [term_id] => 25
        [name] => Team name 1
        [slug] => team-name-1
        [term_group] => 0
        [term_taxonomy_id] => 25
        [taxonomy] => team_names
        [description] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin nec pellentesque sapien.
        [parent] => 22
        [count] => 1
        [image_id] => 90
    )
```

How would i query part of this object (likely as a foreach or as a WP_Query) so it will return the sub categories and their relavant values (title, image,etc)? Is the 'get_terms()' function the right way to go for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `parent` argument in `get_terms()` to get direct children of a term.
You can use the `child_of` argument to get all descendents of a term.

Something like this.

```
$parent_id = 32;
$args = array(
    'parent' => $parent_id
);
$terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, $args );   
print_r( $terms );
```

If you want to programmatically get parent terms and within the loop get sub-categories, you could do something like this.

```
$taxonomy = 'your_tax';
$args = array(
    'parent' => 0 // to get only parent terms
);
$terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, $args );

foreach( $terms as $term ) {
    $children = get_terms( $taxonomy, array(
        'parent' => $term->term_id;
    ) );

    print_r( $children );
}
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms

Answer (score 1):

Since wordpress 4.5.0, taxonomies should be passed through 'taxonomy' argument in $args array :

```
$parent_id = 32;
$args = array(
    'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
    'parent' => $parent_id
);
$terms = get_terms( $args );   
print_r( $terms );
```

[get_terms in official doc](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="categories-item">
  <?php 
  $wcatTerms = get_terms('service_cat', array('hide_empty' => 0, 'parent' =>0)); 

  foreach($wcatTerms as $wcatTerm) :

  ?>
    <button class="accordion"><?php echo $wcatTerm->name; ?></button>
    <div class="panel">
     <?php 
  $wcatTerms1 = get_terms('service_cat', array('hide_empty' => 0, 'parent' =>$wcatTerm->term_id)); 
  foreach($wcatTerms1 as $wcatTerm1) :
     ?>
      <a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $wcatTerm1->slug, $wcatTerm1->taxonomy ); ?>"><?php echo $wcatTerm1->name; ?></a>
      <?php endforeach ;  ?>
    </div>
   <?php endforeach ;  ?>


    <!-- <button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
    <div class="panel">

    </div> -->

</div>
```